# How to exchange factory() function in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I learn Laravel from the tutorial and there is use `factory()`. In my project show me an error, `Undefined function factory`. I know that in Laravel 9 `factory()` does not exist, but someone could help me how can I modify the below code that will run in Laravel 9.
public function run(Faker $faker)
{

```
    factory(
        Task::class,
        $faker->numberBetween(25, 50)
    )->create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`factory()` was used until Laravel 8. In newer versions of Laravel model factories are used: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-factories#main-content

Comment: I add `Task::factory() ->numberBetween(25, 50)->create();` but show me error `Method 'numberBetween' not found in \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory`

Comment: Please read documentation. First you need to add `HasFactory` trait into your model, then you need to create Factory class where you have to add your fake data definitions.

Comment: I don't understand how change this